# Is it possible to export a Seaborn Heatmap into an Excel document?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe/crosstab that I am able to export to an .xlsx document, but it's plainly formatted.  I've messed around and created Seaborn Heatmap visualizations with the dataframe, but would love to have the Seaborn Heatmap formatting within the excel spreadsheet.  Is this possible?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The seaborn heatmap is an image. You can place images into Microsoft programs.

Comment: You can also use [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html) if you want to save directly to a workbook.